# ECS Fargate shutdown and decrement desired count in task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I would like to shut down a task once I've detected there is no more work. The task is part of fargate target group with autoscaling rules so simply doing an `ecs.stop_task(cluster=cluster_arn, task=task_id)` won't work as the group will add another task to meet the desired task count. I want something like [auto_scaling.terminate_instance_in_auto_scaling_group(InstanceId=instance_id, ShouldDecrementDesiredCapacity=True)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.terminate_instance_in_auto_scaling_group) but instance ID seems like an ECS thing and is not present in the task Metadata. I know theres a URI that provides instance ID for EC2, would that work here? Whats the best way to achieve this, specifically with the `boto3` library?

EDIT #1:
Is there a way to decrement desired count with ECS?

Comment: What is triggering the auto-scaling? What metric is auto-scaling targeting? Ideally the auto-scaling would be detecting if there is work, and scaling the tasks up/down accordingly.

Comment: @MarkB the scale out works great but the scaling is based on custom queue size, not whether the worker has finished processing what was pulled off the queue. the task itself has a done callback and I would like to shutdown and scale-in within that callback.

Comment: You will need to call out to the auto-scaling API to reduce the number of desired tasks before shutting down the task.

Comment: @MarkB so the method I linked to in my question won't work for this I assume? If not and I reduce the desired task count prior to `stop_task` will the gap between one command and the other cause the auto scaler to possibly select a different task for shutdown before I make the stop task call?

Comment: If your tasks are handling their own shutdown process, instead of letting the auto-scaling scale down as needed, then you need to enable scale-in protection on all your tasks https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-scale-in-protection.html Then your tasks can reduce the desired count, and shut down as they want.

Comment: @MarkB the problem with this is what happens when several tasks want to shut down simultaneously? `update_service` doesn't have an atomic decrement option for desired count which means a read with `describe_services` to get the current desired count and then write with `update_service`. With hundreds of concurrent tasks, I would think I need something that shuts down and decrements in one operation.

Comment: You're trying to short-circuit the auto-scaling, this is the best you can do with auto-scaling. It sounds like you really shouldn't be using auto-scaling at all, but maybe just a Lambda function that launches ECS tasks (not services).